# Component variables undefined inside subscribe function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm making an API call inside of an `ngOnInit` in my component. The API returns an array of type `Player`.

Each `Player` object has a property `Position`. I'm mapping the result of the API call in `switchMap` of rxjs, to a component variables called `players`.

In the `.subscribe` I'm attempting to loop through the result, and `.push` the object to another component array, depending on the `position` property of `player`.

However, each of the position arrays (`goalkeepers`, `defenders`, `midfielders`, `forwards`), are undefined when I try to `push` the object.

```
    this.http.get<Player[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(result => {
          return this.players = result;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
          if (this.players[i].position == 1) {
            this.goalkeepers.push(result[i]);
          }
        }
      }, error => console.error(error));
```

`this.players` and `this.goalkeepers` are both of type `player[]`.

My understanding here is that the for loop would continue going through each player in this.players, and assigning them to the appropriate position array, but the position arrays are undefined.

In this case the error reads `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. So my understanding is that the `this.goalkeepers` is undefined.

Comment: Point in the question, what is undefined? is it `result[i]`? Also there is no need of using a `switchMap`, If you are not doing anything extra, use a `tap()` or at max use `map()`. Your usage of `switchMap()` is incorrect, it should return an Observable

Comment: In this case the error reads `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. So my understanding is that the `this.goalkeepers` is undefined. Could I just return the result and do all the logic in the subscribe then?

Comment: Very first thing, replace `swicthMap()` with `tap()`. Now if it says `this.goalkeepers` is undefined, then please show us where have you defined it.

Comment: I have it between the class definition and constructor at the top of the `public players: Player[];
  public goalkeepers: Player[];`

Comment: Initialize them like:  `public players: Player[] = []; public goalkeepers: Player[] = [];`

Comment: Alright so that's what I was doing wrong. Also change switchMap to tap(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of `switchMap()`, you can set the `players` property under a `tap()` in the observable. To push data in `goalkeepers` you must initialize it first.

```
this.goalkeepers: Player[] = []    

this.http.get<Player[]>(url).pipe(
        tap(result => this.player = result)
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
          if (this.players[i].position == 1) {
            this.goalkeepers.push(result[i]);
          }
        }
      }, error => console.error(error));
```

Using `tap()` to set `players` is useful if you have multiple subscriptions for `this.http.get<Player[]>(url)` and you don't want to assign `players` individually(which you can do under `subcription` itself). If there's only one subscription then assignment under the subscription would be fine.